Hibernate: use field of parameter
I'd like to write an HQL query looking something like this
UPDATE t SET f1 = (:my_object).f1 WHERE id = (:my_object).f2;
.... /* in the Java code */
myQuery.setParameter("my_object", fooObject);

Is there any syntax that supports this? Obviously I can use two different parameters, but that always introduces the possibility that a different my_object will be set on them by mistake.

Please avoid setting multiple unrelated parameters and ensure data consistency. HQL doesn't directly support setting object properties within the query itself.
